# Find image of two variables function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, absolute-value

I have problem with proving using double inclusion that it's an image of function where we have open interval for instance:

Find image $f[A]$ where $A=(0,2) \times (1,3)$ of $f(x,y)=|x-y|$.

My try:

we have $0<x<2$ and $1<y<3$ so $-3<x-y<1$ hence $0\le|x-y|<3$ so I proved that $f[A] \subseteq [0,3)$ and I have problem with the other inclusion since I can't take the edge value of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: For any $\epsilon > 0$, let $y = 3 - \dfrac12 \epsilon$, $x = \dfrac12 \epsilon$. Then $|x - y| = 3 - \epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, but is it ends the proof of inclusion ?

Comment: Your first (now deleted) comment was right, you want to show for every such $t$, there exist $x,y$ so that $f(x,y) = t$. So my comment doesn't complete the proof, but shows you how to deal with $t$ *close to, but not equal to* $3$.

Comment: I have some problem with notation and I don't quite comprehend how should it look. I have to show for $t \in [0,3)$ there are $x,y$ such that $f(x,y)=t$ and typically I set here some values for $x$ or $y$ and show that then $f(x,y) \in A$ but here I am not sure I set at the same time $y=3-\frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ and $x=\frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ ? I stuck at this moment

Comment: Ok, maybe my hints were more confusing than anything. Look at copperhat's picture, notice that the line $y = 3 - x$ with $x \in (0,2)$ runs nicely through the domain, and crosses the lines where $f(x,y) = 2$, where $f(x,y) = 0$, etc. Note that along this line segment, $f(x,y) = |x - (3 - x)| = |3 - 2x|$ which takes values in $[0,3)$ if $x \in (0,2)$. Thus, setting $t = 3 - 2x$, let $x = \dfrac12 (3 - t)$, and $y = 3 - x = 3 - \dfrac12(3 - t) = \dfrac12(3 + t)$. You can check that these $x,y$ are in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for patience ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to draw a picture.

From the picture, we expect the larger values of $f$ to be at the upper left and lower right. Since $f(x,y) \ge 0$ and $({3 \over 2},{3 \over 2}) \in A $, we expect that
$f(A) = [0,3)$.

[image]

It is easy to show that $y \le 3$ if $y \in f(A)$, however $3 \notin f(A)$. From the picture, we can see that $(x, 3-x) \in f(A)$ for $x \in [{3 \over 
2},0) $ and since $f(x,3-x) = |3-2x|$, we see that $[0,3) \subset f(A)$.

Here is another approach:

First consider the range of values of $x-y$: We have $0<x<2$ and $1<y<3$ so
since $-3 < -y < -1$, we have $-3 < x-y < 1$. In particular, the range of values that $x-y$ takes in $A$ is **exactly** $(-3,1)$. Now look at the range of values that the function $t \mapsto |t|$ can take on $(-3,1)$. This gives $[0,3)$.

Comment: I don't get it , how did you construct this lines ?

Comment: For example, the set of points satisfying $f(x,y) = 2$ is given by solving $x-y=2$ or $x-y=-2$ (these are two of the lines above), the middle line comes from solving $f(x,y) = 0$ which gives the line $x=y$.

Comment: OK, but can you solve this problem with method as I talk at comment or just show how to start because I can't comprehend your method

Comment: I added another approach above that involves writing $f=g \circ h$, where $h(x,y) = x-y$ and $g(t) = |t|$.

Comment: yes but I think you show what I write at 'my try' it's just one inclusion

Comment: I don't understand. You know $0\le |x-y| <3$ (so $f(A) \subset [0,3)$), and furthermore for every value $v \in [0,3)$ there is some $(x,y) \in A$ such that $|x-y| = v$ (so $[0,3) \subset f(A)$).

Comment: I don't see where you prove that for $v \in [0,3)$ we the inclusion

Comment: I have it above, but here is another explicit way: Let $v \in [0,3)$. Show that $({3 -v \over 2}, {3+v \over 2}) \in A$ and $f(({3 -v \over 2}, {3+v \over 2})) = v$.